# How do I make a <div> slide back and forth on click?

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle, slide, reverse

I am writing a design where the right side of a mask (#face2) is sliding from left to right and back again when you click on one of the options (#menu1contact) in the left menu, revealing an inner content (#content).

Here's my code:

```
$('#menu1contact').on('click', function(){

    $('#face2').animate({
    'marginLeft': '+=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').animate({
    'width': '+=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').css('border-left' , 'solid #5d3f35') 
});
```

But how do I make it slide back to its original position when you click on the #menu1contact again?

The following code didn't work:

```
$('#menu1contact').toggle(function(){

    $('#face2').animate({
    'marginLeft': '+=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').animate({
    'width': '+=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').css('border-left' , 'solid #5d3f35')}, 

           function(){

    $('#face2').animate({
    'marginLeft': '-=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').animate({
    'width': '-=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').css('border-left' , 'solid #5d3f35') 
});
```

Comment: Show the relevant HTML and CSS please.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to check the state:

```
$('#menu1contact').on('click', function(){
    if ( !$(this).hasClass("opened") ) {
    $('#face2').animate({
    'marginLeft': '+=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').animate({
    'width': '+=750px'
    },2500);
    $('#content').css('border-left' , 'solid #5d3f35'); 
    $(this).addClass("opened");
    } else {
       $('#face2').animate({
    'marginLeft': '-=750px'
    },2500)
    $('#content').animate({
    'width': '-=750px'
    },2500);
    $('#content').css('border-left' , 'solid #5d3f35');
     $(this).removeClass("opened");
    }
});
```

However you missed some semicolons at the end of rows